# NGINX or Apache2 reverse proxy to a server with client certificate authentication

Tags: apache, nginx, certificate, reverse-proxy, client-certificates

Below is the setup of the infrastructure:

[image]

Assume that it's not possible for the script/computer to authenticate with the certificate. I really need the intermediate reverse NGINX/APACHE2 proxyserver to strip the SSL authentication.

Any idea how I do this in the configuration of NGINX or APACHE2?